# How to read in 2 values of a single quotation/apostrophe between a delimiter without masking the delimiter?

Tags: csv, sas, apostrophe, quotation-marks, single-quotes

I am reading in a text file where 2 character variables both have a value of an apostrophe ' separated by a comma delimiter in di studio. 
Di is reading it as the apostrophes are masking the comma, taking the comma as the value rather than the apostrophes as the value.

An example of the record looks like

```
    95,',',,,word
```

This should give me:

```
    Var1 = 95
    Var2 = '
    Var3 = '
    Var4 = .
    Var5 = .
    Var6 = word
```

Instead I get:

```
    Var1 = 95
    Var2 = ,
    Var3 = .
    Var4 = .
    ...
```

What informats do I need to use or options do I need to set other than delimiter set to a comma?
(Di options preferably,  but base SAS options would help as well).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your text file behave if one of the character variables contains a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are **not** using the `dsd` option on your `infile` statement. Provided that none of the character variables ever contain commas, something like the following should work:

```
data want;
infile cards dlm=',' missover;
input var1 :8. (var2-var6) (:$4.);
cards;
95,',',,,word
;
run;
```

If the character variables in your file do occasionally contain commas and they are not quoted, there may be no consistent way to read your file.

Comment: Good afternoon user667488, many thanks for your reply as I am very grateful. The problem is that some other variables genuinely have a single apostrophe in the data. I have tried doing it without DSD and it causes issues as it then does not read in the missing values when their are consecutive delimiters. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to provide an example seen in your data where this approach doesn't work.